# Can't find mp4 Files querying mediastore

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I got a MP4 File (MIME_TYPE = audio/x-m4a) which I can't find querying `mediastore`.

I don't know if it's a video or an audio file, so I try to query File table of `mediastore` (also check video and audio table with same result).

The file is stored in Music/MP4TestFiles Folder on internal storage (not on an SD-Card, not stored in internal app storage).

Testing on Android 13.

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
String audiodir = "%MP4TestFiles%";
String[] projection = new String[] {
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID};

String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH+ " like ? ";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {audiodir};

String sortOrder = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " ASC";
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,sortOrder);

if (cur == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "mp4...no file found in Directory: "+audiodir);
    } else if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "mp4 Failed to move cursor to first row (no query results). 1");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "mp4 files found")
    }
```

Permission is set in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>
```

If I rename the file into m4b, I got a result.

Any suggestions what's going wrong?

Thanks,
GGK

Comment: `file is stored in Music/MP4TestFiles` Well then String audiodir = "Music/MP4TestFiles";

Comment: no, thats not correct, as I use %DIR% and like operator in query